# WebApp2 - self.request is returning a NoneType object

Tags: python, webapp2

I can't seem to get to the bottom of this.

I've got a class that inherits from webapp2's RequestHandler:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def set_secure_cookie(self, name, val):
        cookie_val = make_secure_val(val)
        self.response.headers.add_header(
        'Set-Cookie',
        '%s=%s; Path=/' % (name, cookie_val))

    def read_secure_cookie(self, name):
        cookie_val = self.request.cookies.get(name)
        return cookie_val and check_secure_val(cookie_val)

    def login(self, user):
        self.set_secure_cookie('user_id', str(user.key().id()))

    def logout(self):
        self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'user_id=; Path=/')

    def initialize(self, *a, **kw):
        webapp2.RequestHandler.initialize(self, *a, **kw)
        uid = self.read_secure_cookie('user_id')
        self.user = uid and User.by_id(int(uid))
```

I setup the cookie on login, but when I try to access `read_secure_cookie` I get the following response:

```
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/coreator/website.py", line 63, in read_secure_cookie
    cookie_val = self.request.cookies.get(name)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cookies'
```

Does anyone have any idea why self.request is a NoneType?

I should add that it's being called within an Endpoints class:

```
@endpoints.api(name = 'users', version = 'v1.00',
               description = 'User Management Resources')
class UsersApi(remote.Service, MainHandler):
```

Comment: Because you're accessing it during initialization instead of when an actual request is made

Comment: That's strange... I have the exact code running just fine on a web app, but it seems to fail if I try to implement this code with Endpoints. Are you sure?

Comment: No it was just a solid guess. Next time you should mention that the code works in production

Comment: Indeed it does, but only in a separate project. Im sort of trying to piece together a user system for Endpoints. Nevertheless, it shouldn't be a NoneType. Hey I'll take any solid guesses at this point lol

Comment: Okay so I understand now that the request object is not available in the Endpoint because im not operating within a get() or post(). Is there any way to access the request object?